# Biblioteca GoogleSearch não funciona

Tags: python

Criei uma ferramenta (python 3.7) a um tempo atrás utilizando a biblioteca googlesearch e funcionava normalmente, resolvi utiliza-la hoje e notei que está dando problema na biblioteca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
from googlesearch import search

print(
    """

    banner     


    """
)

# Pegar tipo de conteúdo
print("Exemplos de conteúdo: Hacking, Forum, eBooks")
conteudo = str(input("Conteúdo:"))


# Dork para encontrar os URLS/LINKS/SITES
dork = f'{conteudo} site:onion.link | site:onion.cab | site:onion.sh | site:tor2web.fi | site:onion.direct'


# Menu de escolhas/seleção


def menu():
    banner = '''


    +-------------------------------------------------------+
    '''

    print(banner)

def escolha():
    print("0. Sair")
    print("1. Sites Onion")
    print("2. Créditos")


menu()

while True:
    escolha()
    menuzinho = int(input("Selecione uma opção: "))
    if menuzinho == 0:
        print("Até a proxima")
        break
    elif menuzinho == 1:
        with open("site.txt", "w") as stream:
            for url in search(dork, stop=50 or 1):
                print(url, file=stream)
            print("-----------------------------------------------------")
            print("Os links foram salvos no seguinte txt: site.txt")
            print("-----------------------------------------------------")
    elif menuzinho == 2:
        print("")
        print("Criado por")
        print("")
        input("Pressione ENTER para continuar")
    else:
        print("Essa opção não existe, tente novamente!")
```

Comment: você deve, nesse meio tempo, ter criado um arquivo com o nome "googlesearch.py" no mesmo diretório que está o seu programa de testes. O Python então importa o seu arquivo, em vez da biblioteca.

Comment: Como resolvo isso?

Comment: mude o nome do arquivo que tem nome identico ao da biblioteca para outro. Senão, a busca feita pelo Python durante o comando `import` sempre vai achar esse arquivo primeiro e ignorar a biblioteca.

Comment: No entanto, parece que não é seu caso - o erro que você colou indica que o Python está pegando o arquivo correto da biblioteca.

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando usar a biblioteca da forma errada - 
a chamada `search` não é uma função da biblioteca `googlesearch`, e sim, um método da classe `GoogleSearch`. Esta classe sim, pode ser importada da biblioteca.

Isso é facilmente observável no exemplo curto de uso na página de download da biblioteca (https://pypi.org/project/google-search/):

```
from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch

response = GoogleSearch().search("something")
for result in response.results:
    print("Title: " + result.title)
    print("Content: " + result.getText())
```

(observe: `from googlesearch import GoogleSearch` e não  `from googlesearch import search` -- pode até ser que isso tenha funcionado algum dia, mas se é o caso, foi numa versão anterior da biblioteca)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wNaCJWL.png